# Doctrine2 fetching rows that have manyToMany association by QueryBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

everyone.
I have 2 entities City and POI. Mapping looks like this:

```
class City {
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="POI", mappedBy="cities")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"position" = "ASC"})
 */
protected $pois;
```

and

```
class POI {
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="City", inversedBy="pois")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="poi_cities")
 */
protected $cities;
```

I would like to fetch all POIs that have at least 1 association with some City using QueryBuilder. I should probably use exists() function but I don't quiet know how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd have to `Left join` them and check if `cities` is null.

```
$qb->select('p', 'c')
   ->from('AcmeDemoBundle:POI', 'p')
   ->leftJoin('p.cities', 'c')
   ->where('c IS NOT NULL');
```

I haven't tested it, but I hope it gives you the general direction. You can read more about the `QueryBuilder` from [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/query-builder.html).

Comment: This is syntacically correct, except from the wrong namespace separator ":" which should be "\" (backslash). However, its probably faster and more clear to do an innerJoin instead of a leftJoin with additional where clause.

Comment: @Max I'm pretty sure the separator should be ":" since I have used it myself. It would, indeed, probably be faster to use innerJoin. The results should actually be grouped as well.

Comment: oh, you are right about the separator, overlooked the symfony 2 tag ;) Dunno what you mean by  "The results should actually be grouped as well.", but yeah.

Comment: @Max Well, both inner and left joins can return several POIs with the same id (for every City a POI has), at least in plain SQL it would. I'm not sure if Doctrine handles this or not off the top of my head.

Comment: I see… Doctrine handles this for you and flattens returned rows so that POIs collection contains unique objects (uniqueness based on the primary key of the entity).

Answer (score 2):

Docrine2 was changed in 2013, so the other solution displays error `Error: Cannot add having condition on a non result variable.` Now we cannot use joined alias just as a condition variable. We should use any of its properties like `c.id`

So you should fix the code to

```
$qb->select('p', 'c')
   ->from('AcmeDemoBundle:POI', 'p')
   ->leftJoin('p.cities', 'c')
   ->where('c.id IS NOT NULL');
$results = $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

If you want to select entities that **does not have any** cities, use `IS NULL`.

```
$qb->leftJoin('p.cities', 'city')
    ->where('city.id IS NULL')
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Description of a problem and link to the commit that responsible for that - http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2780