# Doctrine2 Selecting entity objects with no associated objects

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I can't seem to figure this out although it should be fairly simple thing.

I have Image entity and Article entity. Same image can be used by many articles but each article can only have one image so they are mapped as OneToMany<->ManyToOne.

Now, I need to select **only** images that don't have any articles associated with them. How do I do this?

I tried:

```
$repository->createQueryBuilder('i')
->select('i')
->where('count(i.articles) = NULL');
```

but it doesn't work. How can I achieve this ?

## Update

I'm using this in Type class and am trying to create entity field with only unused entities, here is full function code if it's relevant:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('images', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'BloggerBlogBundle:Image',
                'query_builder' =>
                    function(EntityRepository $er)
                    {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('i')->.........here goes query creation

                                                    },
            )
        )
        ;
}
```

Here is the association too if needed:

Image Class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Blog", mappedBy="image")
 */
protected $articles;
```

Blog Class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Image", inversedBy="articles")
 */
protected $image;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$qb->createQueryBuilder();
->select('i');
->from('BloggerBlogBundle:Image', 'i')
->leftJoin('i.articles', 'a')
->where('a is NULL');
```

Comment: If I use this, I get: `Warning: Missing argument 1 for Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::createQueryBuilder()`.

If I use the same code but first call as `createQueryBuilder('i'), I get:
`Warning: Missing argument 2 for Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::from()`

Comment: @igorpan, I missed the arguments in `form()` function. Post updated

Comment: I get class not defined error, but i tried same thing using: ->from('Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Image', 'i'). Now it gives me: `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 96 near 'i LEFT JOIN i.articles': Error: 'i' is already defined.`

Comment: Does this happen because I used ->createQueryBuilder('i') ? Because I can't run createQueryBuilder without arguments. If I do, I get "missing argument" error.

Comment: could you post the both models? Article and Image

Comment: I managed to make it working without errors but I get empty result always. 

Sure, Image: http://hastebin.com/qukeqelicu.tex
Blog (it should be named 'article' actually,I should refactor this to avoid confusion): http://hastebin.com/xohasujute.php

Comment: Here is code that works but returns me empty array even though it shouldn't be: http://hastebin.com/damipefiju.coffee . Note: $em is EntityManager object passed to function.

Comment: Ok, got it working by combining answers of you two ! Thanks a lot! Could you update your code to exactly the one from my answer so I can accept it to give you credit ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the `count()` function there and `... = NULL` needs to be changed to `... is NULL` in order for Doctrine to do its job.

Total:

```
$repository->createQueryBuilder('i')
    ->select('i')
    ->where('i.articles is NULL');
```

Comment: I get this when using your suggestion: `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 56 near 'articles is ': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.` .Same as manix's answer, if I use `createQueryBuilder` without parameters I get an error, so I used `createQueryBuilder('i')`

Comment: Oke, yes I did not know where you used this code. If you used it in the repository of the image I think you don't need the parameter there.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer no longer works - you have to add `.id` to the where expression:

```
$qb->createQueryBuilder();
 ->select('i');
 ->from('BloggerBlogBundle:Image', 'i')
 ->leftJoin('i.articles', 'a')
 ->where('a.id is NULL');
```

taken from
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30034662/1358376